# How to capture curl_errno in curl_multi mode?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

For some reason `curl_errno($value)` always returns `0` instead of `6` when I try url like `stkovrflow.com`. This is a non existing domain. So curl supposed to return `6`. But i'm getting `0`.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

This is how I check curl error

```
if (curl_errno($value) !== 0)
{
   $handles[$key]['error_code'] = curl_errno($value);
}
```

Here is my full code

```
<?php

protected function curl($url)
    {

        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        $handles = array();
        foreach ($url as $link)
        {
            $handles[$link] = curl_init($link);

            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link],CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->curlFollowLocation);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $this->curlMaxRedirects);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->curlTimeout);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->curlUserAgent);
            curl_setopt($handles[$link], CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);


            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $handles[$link]);
        }

        $running = null;


        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
            usleep(200000);
        } while ($running > 0);

        foreach ($handles as $key => $value)
        {
            $handles[$key] = false;
            $handles[$key]['error_code'] = false;
            if (curl_errno($value) !== 0)
            {
                $handles[$key]['error_code'] = curl_errno($value);
            } else {
                $response = curl_multi_getcontent($value);
                $httpCode = curl_getinfo($value, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                if ( $httpCode != 200 ) {
                    $handles[$key]['error_code'] = $httpCode;
                } else {

                    $handles[$key]['html'] = $response;

                }
            }
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $value);
            curl_close($value);
        }

        curl_multi_close($mh);
        return $handles;
    }
```

### Update:

Looks like curl_errno does not work ([see bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60660)) in curl multi mode. Instead we should use [curl_multi_info_read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php). When I use [curl_multi_info_read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php) like this

```
$e_code = curl_multi_info_read($mh);
var_dump($e_code);
```

this is my var_dump output.

```
array (size=3)
  'msg' => int 1
  'result' => int 6
  'handle' => resource(7, curl)
```

As you can it returns 6 correctly. But php doc says

> **The data the returned resource points to will not survive calling curl_multi_remove_handle().**

Unfortunately my script depends on curl_multi_remove_handle(). Any solution?

=======

Comment: Are you sure that domain doesn't exist? Many ISPs are now having their dns servers serve up ads/redirects instead of a proper NX failed dns response. What does `gethostbyname('stkovrflow.com')` return? If you get a valid IP from that, then your ISP is futzing around

Comment: Don't call `curl_multi_remove_handle()` before you get and save the data you want - the `errno` -